# Dayjs difference between two date time has a default of 8hours

Tags: javascript, datetime, dayjs

I am confused why the difference between these two dates has a default of 8 hours? I am expecting a result something like 00:12:32 at least in my case from the time I posted this. Right now, in the result, the hour has a default of 8.

```js
const date1 = dayjs(Date.now())
const date2 = dayjs(1674235010388)

// Check date date1
console.log('date1 =', dayjs(date1).format('hh:mm:ss'))

// Check date2 date
console.log('date2 =', dayjs(date2).format('hh:mm:ss'))

const result = date1.diff(date2)
console.log(dayjs(result).format('hh:mm:ss'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it does not depend on `Date.now()` (you can simply replace `Date.now()` with its value when run on your machine). That way the question makes sense for anyone coming to this question in the future. Without the date portion showing in the logged dates, it makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell you but it is another reason for not using these frameworks when plain JS is more predictible

```js
const ms2hhmmss = ms => new Date(ms).toISOString().slice(11,19); // grab the time from YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.milZ

const date1 = new Date()
const date2 = new Date(1674235010388)
console.log(date1)
console.log(date2)

const diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2)
console.log(ms2hhmmss(diff))
```

Comment: Thank you. I am building a very simple time tracker app(my first app), that is the reason why I use this library. Your solution works even with the data from the server. One question, what is the purpose of  slice(11,19)?

Comment: It grabs the time from the [Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) which is in the format `2023-10-05T14:48:00.000Z`

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to do it with dayjs and the duration plugin, in case anyone comes here looking for that answer. For some reason I had to make the loading of the duration plugin async and wire it up manually. I expect it has something to do with a) Stack Snippets and b) the lack of caffeine in my brain.

@mplungjan is correct, of course, it's quite simple without dayjs as well.

```js
document.querySelector('#duration').onload = (e) => {
  dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_duration);

  const date1 = dayjs(Date.now())
  const date2 = dayjs(1674235010388)
  // Check date date1
  console.log('date1 =', date1.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'))

  // Check date2 date
  console.log('date2 =', date2.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'))

  const result = dayjs.duration(date1.diff(date2));
  console.log(result.format('HH:mm:ss'))
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-hcV6DX35BKgiTiWYrJgPbu3FxS6CsCjKgmrsPRpUPkXWbvPiKxvSVSdhWX0yXcPctOI2FJ4WP6N1zH+17B/sAA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/plugin/duration.min.js" integrity="sha512-QxVJ3lAILV0RSq3wPNV5CFNyyywxd5QfA9jfGfzVViwpL/eWSi5dR1nZMc02c+QE4xz2L1eQvx/fn18RrUq9lw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" id="duration" async></script>
```